# Ctrl+Kでコードサンプルにできるのは、このサイト固有の機能ですか？

Tags: サポート, エディタ

StackOverflow以外のサイト（外部の投稿サイト）では
Ctrl + K
でコードサンプルの表示ができないのですが、
このサイト固有の機能でしょうか？

Comment: 投稿する際のコード整形のことでしょうか。例えば私の環境では英語版StackOverflowでも使えていますが、どのサイトで動かないのでしょうか？

Comment: StackOverflow以外のサイト（外部の投稿サイト）で使えないのですが、この機能はStackOverflow固有の機能ですか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

現在 Stack Exchange ネットワークで使われているエディタは PageDown というライブラリです。

[pagedown - A JavaScript Markdown converter and editor - Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown)

「Markdown のコードブロックでマークアップする」機能、またそのショートカットである <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> はこのライブラリによるものです。これを使っているサイトであれば同じ機能が使えるかもしれませんが、それ以外のサイトでは使えないでしょう。

念のため書いておきますと、Markdownに対応していないサイトの場合、例え手動でインデントしたとしてもコードが見やすく表示されることはないと思います。

参考

- ['editor' tag wiki - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/editor/info)
- [Reverse Engineering the WMD Editor « Blog – Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/)